# how to write fasta file based on functions that you wrote?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I wrote three functions:

1. readCodonFile()
2. readFasta()
3. dna2Protein()

In the last function called generateProteinFile, I call the functions and need to write out the results.

```
def generateProteinFasta(dnaFilename, aaFilename,codonFilename):
    
    tt = readCodonFile(codonFilename)
    dnaSequences = readFasta(dnaFilename)

    for ident,dna in dnaSequences.items():
        print( ident, dna, dna2Protein(dna,tt) )
    
proteinFasta = generateProteinFasta("test.fna", "test_aminos.fasta", "bacterialcode.txt")
```

How can I write the result in generateProteinFasta into a fasta file?

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are looking for exactly. Could you please give an example of the values and desired output? What does `dna2Protein()` return?

Comment: Have you checked out BioPython?

Comment: see https://biopython.org